# Could anyone tell me why my program doesn't work?

Tags: java, integer

The program reads values from scanner until the value 0 is given, which finishes the process. The program will compile the sum only if all the numbers given are integers. In all the other situations (where not all of the values are integers) the program won't give anything out. 
So i noticed my program gives out the sum of the integers even if there are other non integer values given and sometimes when they are all integers given it doesn't show the real sum just one of the numbers or something.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testing3{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum1 = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        String number = input.nextLine();
        int value =Integer.parseInt(number);
        while(true) {
            if (value!=0) {
                number = input.nextLine();
                if (Math.round(value)==value)//condition to integer{
                    sum1 = sum1 + value;
            } else {
                System.out.println(sum1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `nextDouble()` if you want to read *integers*?. Why not `nextInt()`?. Also, I think you should use `nextLine()` to read the input and try parsing the value as an int, catch the exception and decide what to do. (Or match the pattern and then parse)

Comment: Then again, if you need to read anything, but only show the sum if all values were ints, you might want to read them in as Strings (`nextLine()`?) and check if they are ints or not.

Comment: Because the user should have the right to write any number in the scanner .. if i just put int and the user put decimal the process would end , i need the process to end only if the user puts a 0 .

Comment: Then read the input as a String. After that check if it's an int or not (you can use `Integer.parseInt()` for this.

Comment: could you check it now ? i made some changes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `while(true)` or `for(;;)` to make in infinite loop

Second use `nextInt()` to read integers instead of doubles because you have no use for doubles. Alternatively, read strings with `readLine` and check their validity with `Integer.parseInt`.

Thirdly, you have a syntax error (so it shouldn't compile). You have an unmatched close brace near the else.

Lastly, remove the `if (number != 0)` because that will cause your program to continuously repeat in the loop without doing anything forever. Change the inside of the loop to:

```
number = input.nextInt();
if (number != 0){
    sum1 = sum1 + number; //or use sum1 += number
} else {
    System.out.println(sum1);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at the place where you test for an integer. I don't think x mod 1 == 0 is correct suitable here. What I'll do when I am asked to check whether a number is an integer, I round the number and check if it equals to the original number.

Let's say we have a `double` variable called x and this evaluates to `true` if x is an integer:

```
Math.round(x) == x
```

I don't know whether there is a better way to do it but that's how I would do it and I like it.